# What are the chances of picking at least all of what we want after randomly picking k times with replacement?

Tags: probability

Lets say I have a bag $S$ of coins labeled from $0$ to $n$, and I am given a unordered list $Q$ where all elements of $Q$ are present in $S$. What are the chances after picking with replacement $k$ times of getting any unordered list $P$ where $Q \subseteq P$?

Let me give an example, say I have a bag of coins $S = \{0,0,1,2,3,3\}$, and I wish to obtain:

- At least Two $0$s
- At least One $1$
- At least Three $2$s

What are the chances of obtaining at least that after randomly picking in the bag $k$ times with replacement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability of getting exactly $m_i$ coins labelled $i$, $i=0\ldots n$,
in $k$ drawings with replacement, where $m_i \ge 0$ and $\sum_i m_i = k$, is
$$ \frac{k!}{m_0! \ldots m_n!} \prod_{i=1}^n p_i^{m_i} $$
where $p_i$ is the probability of getting type $i$ in one drawing (thus 
$N_i/N$ if the drawings are fair, where there are $N$ coins of which $N_i$ are labelled $i$).  For the probability of at least $q_i$ coins of each type, you'd have to sum this over all $m$ where $m_i \ge q_i$ for all $i$.